# not-able-to-open-AWS quicksight-after-migration-from-gsuite-to-office-365

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight, identity-management

I recently migrated my email mailbox and mangement from GSuite to Microsoft office 365. After this I am getting below error while opening quicksight from my AWS account.

**The AWS principal tag corresponding to “PrincipalTag:Email” in your SAML assertion or OIDC token is either an invalid email or not present. Please reach out to your QuickSight account’s admin to ensure that the email address for this AWS principal tag is correct.**

Please let me know if you any solution or document to resolve this.

I checked many AWS SSO document but none are helping. I am using cognito as IDP.